# Salesforce Trust api Call from salesforce

Tags: apex, rest-api, soap-api, tooling-api, trust

Salesforce  provided some apis to make a request and get the salesforc staus in anwhere(like in other app) for dashboards perspectives.
I am not able to get how i can use get request in workbench for getting instance status.
below is the api status **https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs/#/**
[image]

error in workbench
[image]

Please suggest get response from these services in workbench or postman

Comment: Workbench's [REST Explorer](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/quickstart_using_workbench.htm) assumes you're calling one of the core SF platform APIs and `api.status.salesforce.com` is not core. Use another HTTP/REST client for testing.

Comment: could you please provide me more details like what can be the URL to hit in postman .

Comment: You can invoke these APIs from https://api.status.salesforce.com/v1/docs web page